# Predicate<T> from file

Tags: java, json, parsing, predicate

Is there a way to get these parameters from a file (JSON, XML or something parsable from java)? I have a lot of "questions" inside my code and coding inside is obviously not the best way to do it.

```
new Question("Is it a men?", character -> character.isMale(), Question.TYPE.GENDER));
```

---

```
public class Question {

    private final String text;
    private final Predicate<Character> filter;
    private final Question.TYPE type;

    /**
     * @param text testo della domanda
     * @param filter filtro della domanda
     * @param type classe di appartenenza della domanda
     */
    public Question(final String text, final Predicate<Character> filter, final TYPE type) {
        this.text = text;
        this.filter = filter;
        this.type = type;
    }

    /**
     * @return Testo della domanda.
     */
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    /**
     * @return Il filtro necessario per ottenere i personaggi che rispecchiano le caratteristiche fisiche volute.
     */
    public Predicate<Character> getFilter() {
        return filter;
    }

    /**
     * @return la classe di appartenenza della domanda.
     */
    public TYPE getType() { 
        return this.type;
    }

    /**
     * Definisce le classi di appartenenza delle domande, viene utilizzato per escludere le domande che hanno relazioni fra loro.
     */
    public enum TYPE {
        /***/
        HAIR_COLOR, EYE_COLOR, GENDER, GLASSES, HAIR_TYPE, HAT, BEARD;
    }
}
```

----- Character class

```
package model;

import java.util.Optional;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

import utilities.Colors;

public class Character {
    private final String name;
    private final boolean isMale;
    private final Colors eyeColor;
    private final Optional<Colors> hairColor;
    private final Colors skinColor;
    private final boolean hasBeard;
    private final boolean hasMustache;
    private final boolean hasHat;
    private final boolean hasEarings;
    private final boolean hasGlasses;
    private final Hair hairType;
    private final String picPath;

    /**
     * Tipi di capelli.
     */
    public enum Hair {
        /***/
        STRAIGHT, CURLY, BALD;
    }

    /**
     * @param name nome
     * @param isMale genere
     * @param eyeColor colore degli occhi
     * @param hairColor colore dei capelli
     * @param skinColor colore della pelle
     * @param hasBeard .
     * @param hasMustache .
     * @param hasHat .
     * @param hasEarings .
     * @param hasGlasses .
     * @param hairType .
     * @param picPath .
     */
    public Character(final String name, final boolean isMale, final Colors eyeColor, final Optional<Colors> hairColor, final Colors skinColor,
            final boolean hasBeard, final boolean hasMustache, final boolean hasHat, final boolean hasEarings, final boolean hasGlasses,
            final Hair hairType, final String picPath) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.isMale = isMale;
        this.eyeColor = eyeColor;
        this.hairColor = hairColor;
        this.skinColor = skinColor;
        this.hasBeard = hasBeard;
        this.hasMustache = hasMustache;
        this.hasHat = hasHat;
        this.hasEarings = hasEarings;
        this.hasGlasses = hasGlasses;
        this.hairType = hairType;
        this.picPath = picPath;
    }

    /**
     * @return il nome del personaggio
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @return ritorna true se è maschio
     */
    public boolean isMale() {
        return this.isMale;
    }

    /**
     * @return il colore dei capelli del personaggio (Empty se non li ha).
     */
    public Optional<Colors> getHairColor() {
        return this.hairColor;
    }

    /**
     * @return il colore della pelle del personaggio.
     */
    public Colors getSkinColor() {
        return this.skinColor;
    }

    /**
     * @return true se ha la barba
     */
    public boolean hasBeard() {
        return this.hasBeard;
    }

    /**
     * @return true se ha i baffi
     */
    public boolean hasMustache() {
        return this.hasMustache;
    }

    /**
     * @return true se ha il cappello
     */
    public boolean hasHat() {
        return this.hasHat;
    }

    /**
     * @return true se ha gli orecchini/piercing
     */
    public boolean hasEarings() {
        return this.hasEarings;
    }

    /**
     * @return true se ha gli occhiali
     */
    public boolean hasGlasses() {
        return this.hasGlasses;
    }

    /**
     * @return il tipo di capelli definiti in enum Character.Hair
     */
    public Hair getHairType() {
        return this.hairType;
    }

    /**
     * @return il colore degli occhi del personaggio.
     */
    public Colors getEyeColor() {
        return this.eyeColor;
    }

    /**
     * @return l'immagine che rappresenta il personaggio.
     */
    public ImageIcon getPicPath() {
        return new ImageIcon(this.picPath);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the definition of `Question`; the easiest way would be to serialize and deserialize a collection of `Question` into an xml file. However, I guess the predicate cannot be serialized directly.

Comment: It should be serializable if you cast as such.

Comment: This question will be easier to answer if you add the code for the `Character` class.  I suspect the type enum can be replaced with property names, and the file can simply name a bean property and one or more qualifying values.

Comment: I'm using GSON parser and i think that the real problem it's the Predicate and not my enum TYPE, anyway, any suggestion would be appreciated